# Adding a header to UITableview programmatically

Tags: ios

How would I add this feature programmatically? I'm not sure what I would search to find this. I know how to add the IBAction but not the code to generate this feature highlighted in the picture. Is it a custom cell or a divider?s

[image: http://i40.tinypic.com/hthhdl.png]

Comment: All that is, is a `UITableViewSectionHeader` This link may help https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=UITableViewHeaderFooterView&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr&ei=PEV6UrLMB7KR7AaQvIGwAQ also have a look at the apple documentation for `UITableView` https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 34, accepted):

That's just a header in the TableView, they appear on top of your section

Use this method if you want a title:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Or this one if you want a custom view:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

And for the height:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Answer (score 26):

Try This one Programmatically adding **header** it's Easy..

```
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1, 50, 276, 30)];
headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:235/255.0f green:235/255.0f blue:235/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

UILabel *labelView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 5, 276, 24)];
labelView.text = @"hello";

[headerView addSubview:labelView];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
```

**Or Try in Swift**

```
var headerView: UIView = UIView.init(frame: CGRectMake(1, 50, 276, 30))
headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 235/255.0, green: 235/255.0, blue: 235/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

var labelView: UILabel = UILabel.init(frame: CGRectMake(4, 5, 276, 24))
labelView.text = "hello"

headerView.addSubview(labelView)
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
```

**Swift 4.0 and later**

```
var headerView: UIView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 1, y: 50, width: 276, height: 30))
headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 235/255.0, green: 235/255.0, blue: 235/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

var labelView: UILabel = UILabel.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 4, y: 5, width: 276, height: 24))
labelView.text = "hello"

headerView.addSubview(labelView)
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
```

Comment: Perfect answer. This is what I needed.

Comment: Your Welcome Rizwan Ahmed

Answer (score 14):

**Updated For Swift 4**

Similar to SimplePJ's answer. If you want to create a custom header view for the **ENTIRE TABLE VIEW** you can create one and set it as the tableHeaderView like so.

```
  let headerView: UIView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 1, y: 50, width: 276, height: 30))
  headerView.backgroundColor = .red

  let labelView: UILabel = UILabel.init(frame: CGRect(x: 4, y: 5, width: 276, height: 24))
  labelView.text = "My header view"

  headerView.addSubview(labelView)
  self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
```

This is not to be confused with creating a **table view section header** in which you'd use the following method.

```
func headerView(forSection section: Int) -> UITableViewHeaderFooterView?
```

The return value is the header view associated with the **section**, or nil if the section does not have a header view.

Comment: @freeddieoh Thank you so much you save my day.

Answer (score 7):

Just implement these two delegate methods in your TableViewController

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

In the first method return the height of the header view,
In the second return the view that should be displayed

here is an example

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 55.0;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"simpleHeader.png"]];
}
```