# ImageView top of the UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scroll

My question is very basic: I want to create a view controller that at the top of the page is a static image and under of that there is a UITableView.  And when I scroll, both page tableview and image scroll.

If there are any questions, please ask me.  Thank you.

Comment: You can use a header: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19813412/adding-a-header-to-uitableview-programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way: you just need to drop a UIView inside your table view on storyboard and than there you can add your image view as you want.